# C# Remove unused index in an array with a declared size

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an assignment to make a method. The method requires to ask for a user input and store the user input in an Array, the Array initializes with sentinel values until the array is filled with user input. 
The method will print all the value that user input.

So far, the program works except when the user does not fill all the array. 
It means the array still use the initialized values(sentinel values), It will show a bunch of zeros to the unused index of the array.

For example:
int [] sample = new int[5]; // max size of array
// user input 3 numbers with loop (for ex. 1, 2, 3 and then exits with 555)

how do I make it display as

1
2
3

instead of

1
2
3
0
0

Comment: __Must__ you use an array, rather than a `List<>`? You could have an array of nullable integers, `new int?[5]`.

Comment: You can either use a List or you can count the number of inputs and only display up to that count

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i wouldnt suggest an absolute beginner to use nullable types just yet. there are way better ways to solve it.

Comment: I believe homework questions are generally frowned upon, but the reason you get `1 2 3 0 0` is because you initialize an array of 5 `int` values. The default initialized value of an integer is 0 in C#. when you say **display** are you trying to display just the final value? if so you can loop through the array and build a result variable `result += sample[i].ToString()` and `break` out of the loop if you hit your sentinel value.

Comment: There are 50 different ways you could do it as you are already finding out.  If you have to use an array and you don't have to specify a max size to begin with, you can use the Array.Resize method to change the size each time the user enters something valid....then you don't have to worry about erroneous data in the array at all.

Comment: Note:   this has a performance penalty associated with recreating the array.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new array `int [] sample = new int[5];` it will populate it with zeros if you don't define a default value to initialise it.

The other problem is that if you define an array of 5 elements and user continues to insert data, you won't be able to store that data.
You are better to work with List as you don't need an initial size and you can insert data into it without limite.

```
List<int> usersInts = new List<int>();

userInts.Add(//userInputsHere);
```